# jquery in ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js

My application is supposed to be a single page application and I have the following code that works fine:

home.php:

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

accordion.php:

```
    //Click functions: load content 
    $('#parents').click(function(){
        //Load parent in container
        $('#container').load('http://www.blabla.com/entities/parents/parents.php');
    });
```

parents.php:

```
<div class="entity_wrapper">
    Some divs and selectors 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Some jQuery / javascript 
    }); 
</script>
```

So the content loads fine, while the scripts dynamically loaded execute fine as well.
I apply this system repetitively and it continues to work smoothly.
I've seen that there are a lot of frameworks available on SPA's (such as backbone.js) but I don't understand why I need them if this works fine.

From the backbone.js website:

> When working on a web application that involves a lot of JavaScript,
>   one of the first things you learn is to stop tying your data to the
>   DOM. It's all too easy to create JavaScript applications that end up
>   as tangled piles of jQuery selectors and callbacks, all trying
>   frantically to keep data in sync between the HTML UI, your JavaScript
>   logic, and the database on your server. For rich client-side
>   applications, a more structured approach is often helpful.

Well, I totally don't have the feeling that I'm going through the stuff they mention.
Adding the javascript per page works really well for me.
They are html containers with clear scope and the javascript is just related to that part.
More over, for me the front end doesn't do *that* much, most of the logic is managed based on Ajax calls to external PHP scripts. Sometimes the js can be a bit more extended for some functionalities, but all just loads as smooth in less than a second.

If you think that this is bad coding, please tell me why I cannot do this and more importantly, what is the alternative I should apply. At the moment, I really don't see a reason on why I would change this approach as it just works too well.

I'm kinda stuck on this question because it just worries me sick as it seems too easy to be true. Why would people go through hard times if it would be as easy as this...

**Edited question** based on Juhana's comment:

I don't feel like my project fits the use case Backbone is made for. Should I use it anyway?

Comment: A bit confused by the question---to paraphrase, "I don't feel like my project fits the use case Backbone is made for. Should I use it anyway?"

Comment: If that's what it is, then I will be really happy about it. What I actually want to ask is if what I'm doing is bad practice or simply wrong. Obviously, I would use the tools they offer to create an SPA the way it is advised; but if this works well and there is no reason not to, then I will be at peace if some more experienced web developers can confirm. I'm willing to make my life harder than it is if it makes things better, but I currently don't see a reason to.  I'm confused on why I don't read about this approach - nowhere I've looked on the internet.

Comment: @Juhana I took your paraphrased question and posted it as an edit in my original post. Thanks for notifying me about the confusion.

Comment: bad practice? yes. Wrong? no. Will it bite you in the rear later? maybe, but that depends on how much this application changes over time. Now, when you need to change some specific aspect of your application, you have to find the correct html include that contains the javascript you're after, rather than just finding the javascript. That isn't an issue when the application is small, but when it's much larger, that can be a difficult task.

Comment: You'll also find yourself repeating code as the application grows.

Comment: I'm trying to interpret what you explained. "you have to find the correct html include that contains the javascript you're after, rather than just finding the javascript". I'm sorry, I'm having problems interpreting this correctly. Do you mean including an external js file on the moment that I need it or on page load? Why is this different from including the javascript in script tags? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the level of your apps scalability, ease of maintenance and performance. Looking at your code, you use some old (and to be deprecated) jQuery features so i gather that it was written quite some time ago.

Know that a single page application doesn't ends with data loading and also contains:

- Event bindings
- dynamic data bindings
- multiple views
- reusable UI
- flexible and non-dependant UI controls
- JS logic for parsing, displaying, keeping track and caching your data

For the past year i've been working on an analytics platform that doesn't use a single framework and by chance - we had to implement everything on our own (and done so quite successfully). It's scalable, robust, easy to understand and quite good on the performance bit, however using angular, ember or knockout would have saved us plenty of time since most maintenance is about the level of abstraction of our various core features (detching data, parsing it, keeping track of it etc).

It's also great for testing, which is a huge benefit when your system gets big, since the most important aspect of testing, in my opinion alone - is the dependency tracking it allows so basically, you can stop worrying about working on something - and ruining things that are seemingly unrelated

I think that although client side frameworks have a certain learning curve, some faster than others - it's worth your time since it takes away some of the routines one must constantly implement in his or hers development process.

Comment: Okay thanks, that surely gives me some guidelines to do my research! Just a question: which features are going to be deprecated? I suppose it can't be the document ready, jQuery click or jQuery Ajax. Which one do you mean?

Comment: I'm talking about the click() event which was common back in the day, however, now that i've read some of JQ's documentation, i've seen they've made it an alias of .on("click",) which makes perfect sense.

just another thing - when you place your scripts at the bottom of the <body /> (where you should place all of your scripts - you don't need the $(document).ready() event since by that time, the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: Great, thanks for the tips, that makes sense and I'm learning. I've watched a few presentations on backbone.js yesterday, and it looks very promising. Now I understand its worth, but as you said, it is an approach that requires some initial learning curve and time to get used to. I was wondering if it was really worth my time (hence my original post), but I can more clearly see how it will boost my skills for smarter application design now. Many thanks!

Comment: Good luck, also try this interactive tutorial: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/ - it's about knockoutJS, but it will give you the perspective you need since backbone is much more loose and allows you to stray from some good practices

Comment: Okay; I try to be a best practice man when I'm aware, so I will definitely check out the link Mike. Thanks again for the helpful advice.